# Swift - Why can I not input fetched data from the web into a function with NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: json, parsing, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to pull information from a personal raspberry pi web server and output it within an iOS app. Within the web server I have a php file with the address localhost/test_data. This php file creates a JSON formatted webpage with the data that I want to access. After I get the data at the URL via my GetDataAtURL function, I use the output as an input to the function DataSerialization. The URL I am currently using is a test URL, and I will substitute in my actual URL once it is working. Whenever I call the data DataSerialization function with input "data" (which is the output of the GetDataAtURL function), I receive the error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0".Why am I receiving this error? My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var data : NSData!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos")

    GetDataAtURL(url!) { (resultData) -> Void in
        print(resultData)
        self.data = resultData
    }

   // print(self.data)

    DataSerialization(data)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}


func GetDataAtURL (url : NSURL, completion:(resultData: NSData?) -> Void) {

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data,_,error) -> Void in
if let error = error {

print(error.localizedDescription)

}
completion(resultData: data)

}

dataTask.resume()

}

func DataSerialization (input: NSData) {

do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(input, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let name = json["name"] as? [String] {
        print(name)
    }
    if let full_name = json["full_name"] as? [String] {
            print(full_name)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting self.data in an asynchronous callback. That means the data will be stored at some unknown point in the future after you start reading the data. When you try to process the data, it hasn't been set yet.

Best to find some code samples to see how this is done.